# How to upgrade cordova version 2.7.0 to 3.5.0 ios

Tags: ios, cordova

please help me to upgrade cordova based ios project from version 2.7.0 to 3.5.0 cordova version...
Is there any way to add cordova as a framework in xocde?
Please suggest me better approach for this.

Comment: Could you please list of plugins which you have in your projects? Would be good if you update your question with platforms which you app is running on and which standard plugins are used by the app. Also do you have custom written plugins?

Comment: Developing for ios platform..and we are using custom plugins plus cordova api plugins like device,local storage etc.it wil be very helpful , if share anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the CLI docs (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface), you will see that there is a standard way to do upgrades:

```
cordova platform upgrade android
```

As an example. However, 2.7 is *quite* old. In your case, I'd recommend making a new project (it takes 2 seconds!) and then copying your www files over. Plugins are handled differently in 3.X so keep that in mind.